# Displaying Calendar in month view

Tags: android, calendar

i just wanna know  is it possible to display the Calendar in the month view using the api available. i am searching for while dint find anything to display the calendar in the Month view . kindly help and let me know is this possible using android sdk1.5 or 1.6 or even 2.0. If not what would be the procedure to generate month view and highlighting the present date.

thank you for ur help.

regards
Sheik

Comment: How did you end up resolving this? Did you manage to get a calendar view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Google Calender**](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/provider/Calendar.java) is not part of the SDK application, so it will be difficult to find a way to get the month view.

Keep in mind that the emulator does not have a Calender database, so if you were to test your application it would have to be loaded onto a real device in order to see any results.